# How to format booleans using psql?

Tags: psql

Using `psql`, I would like to format boolean values to display as `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `t` and `f` by default, as I find the latter difficult to distinguish from one another.

I can change how `null` displays by setting the following in my `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\pset null 'Ø'
```

How can I do so for boolean values?

Answer (score 2):

While there doesn't appear to be a simple way to modify the psql output behavior like for the `null` separator, you may achieve this another way, by modifying the output value, casting it to text.

Given a schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE bools (
  name text,
  alive boolean
  );

INSERT INTO bools VALUES ('Taylor Swift', TRUE);
INSERT INTO bools VALUES ('Elvis Presley', FALSE);
```

We can then query for the boolean values, case them along the way, or even create a function that handles the casting for us:

```
postgres=# SELECT name, alive FROM bools;
     name      | alive
---------------+-------
 Taylor Swift  | t
 Elvis Presley | f
(2 rows)

postgres=# SELECT name, alive::text FROM bools;
     name      | alive
---------------+-------
 Taylor Swift  | true
 Elvis Presley | false
(2 rows)

postgres=# SELECT name, UPPER(alive::text) AS alive FROM bools;
     name      | alive
---------------+-------
 Taylor Swift  | TRUE
 Elvis Presley | FALSE
(2 rows)

postgres=# CREATE FUNCTION bool_to_upper(boolean) RETURNS text
postgres-#     AS $$ SELECT UPPER(CAST($1 AS text)) $$
postgres-#     LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=# SELECT name, bool_to_upper(alive) AS alive FROM bools;
     name      | alive
---------------+-------
 Taylor Swift  | TRUE
 Elvis Presley | FALSE
(2 rows)
```

See [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0133a/21) for a working example on Postgresql 9.6.

Comment: Alternately, use pgcli which offers you more, and formats bools as `True,False`. https://www.pgcli.com/

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any settings which allow you to format boolean output like that, but Marko Tikkaja [published a patch](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/56308F56.8060908@joh.to) a few years ago to support this.